# Change from text type to date type in Data Stream in Data Cloud

Tags: date, text, datacloud

Data Stream in Data Cloud wants to create Formula Fields and convert existing text-type columns into date types.

The value of the column in the existing text format is '20231101', and we tried three ways to change it.

1. FORMATDATE(sourceField['SALE_DATE__c'],'yyyy-MM-dd')
2. PARSEDATE(sourceField['SALE_DATE__c'],'yyyy-MM-dd')
3. 

DATE(
LEFT(sourceField['SALE_DATE__c'], 4),
MID(sourceField['SALE_DATE__c'],5,2),
RIGHT(sourceField['SALE_DATE__c'],2)
)

However, there is an error that the formula is incorrect, or a problem that the test proceeds, but the converted value cannot be determined in the Data Explorer.

Does any expert know how to fix this?